# Token syntax to get value of a field inside a workflow?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I've added a Boolean Field (IsUrgent) to many content types, and I've created a workflow that starts when any of those contents is created.

Even though my field is listed in the Token Helper Tooltip, it's not showing anything. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279353/boolean-tokens-in-orchard-cms), it is implied that he can retrieve the boolean value when working on forms, I want to do that but with contents.

I've tried this tokens, also with .Text and .Value at the end, and # before the token bracket:

As it appears in the tooltip: **{Content.Fields.Page.IsUrgent}**

Using request: **{Request.Content.Fields.Page.IsUrgent}**

Using user: **{User.Content.Page.IsUrgent}**

Using Workflow: **{Workflow.State:Content.Page.IsUrgent}**

Using workflow with contentItem:
 **{Workflow.State:Content.ContentItem.Page.IsUrgent}**

If it helps, these are working fine: **{Content.Id} {Content.ContentType}**

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there is a wildcard for a particular field name on any content type. Is that what you're trying to do, or is the issue specifically with boolean-type fields?

Comment: Yes, what I expected was like when you create a Form, you can automatically access any value later in the workflow with the {FormSubmission.Field:*} token, regardless if it's boolean or other. I thought so because the Fields I added to my content, do show in the Token Helper Tooltip, but I guess you still need to create the backend for each Field.